# Unbounded family of isomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose $(T_\alpha)$ is a unbounded in norm family of onto isomorphisms acting on a Banach space. Does it follow that the family $(T_\alpha x)$ is unbounded for any non-zero $x$?

Comment: By "for any", do you mean "for all", or "there exists at least one"?

Comment: For all. There exists at least one follows from Banach-Steinhaus,right?

Comment: Then the answer is no. Consider a product $E\times F$ of Banach spaces, let $S_\alpha \colon E \to E$ an unbounded family of isomorphisms, and consider $T_\alpha = S_\alpha\times \operatorname{id}_F$.

Comment: I see. Any $(0,x)$ does not satisfy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Special case of example given in a comment by Daniel Fischer: 
$$
T_{n}(x,y) = (n x,y),\quad (x,y)\in\mathbb R^2,\ n=1,2,\dots
$$
is a counterexample because $T_n(0,1)=(0,1)$ for all $n$.

(A case could be made that any conjecture  about Banach spaces should be tested on $\mathbb R^2$ first.)